# How can I define a foreign key using netbeans 6.7?

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jpa, foreign-keys

I'm using JPA in netbeans with mysql and I need to define a foreign key. I want to do it graphically because it is very easy to create tables using netbeans 6.7 UI without dealing with SQL commands. Can you tell me how to do it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this tutorial................

http://sageniuz.blogspot.com/2007/11/foreign-keys-in-derby-with-netbeans-6.html